Show a full calendar view for an Event list inside a modern page + allow to "Connect to Outlook"
I want to show a Calendar inside my modern sharepoint online page. Now seems there are 2 ways based on this link https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-calendar-view-on-a-sharepoint-list/.

Create a custom list and use the Calendar view

Create an actual Event list


Now I do not want to use the first option as I cannot use the "Connect to Outlook" to connect the SharePoint calendar to my outlook on Windows machine, as the source is not an actual event but rather a custom list with a calendar view.
But using the second point, I can use the "Connect to Outlook",

but I am unable to show the full calendar view on a modern page in a user friendly way. now i used this Embed web part, with an iframe and IsDlg=1 parameter, as follow:-

but the result i got was not very pleasant, as follow:-

where there is a lot of free space on top + when i click on the "+Add" link to add a new event or click to view existing event >> the event will be shown on the embed web part with all the other screen sections which is not very user friendly, as follow:-

so how i can have a full calendar view inside modern web page in a user friendly and modern way + the ability to use "Connect to Outlook"??
Thanks

IsDlg=1 is used to hide the left navigation bar and top navigation bar, and the blank space above is used to show the drop-down toolbar, so IsDlg=1 is useless.

Embed web part cannot deeply change the CSS of the data source, so the working behavior of the web part will be consistent with the data source. The same is true for the "the event will be shown on the embed web part with all the other screen sections which is not very user friendly" that you find troubling. If this bothers you very much, you may want to try using the modern script editor web part to see if it can achieve your needs.
For your reference:
https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2023/03/15/use-script-editor-modern-sharepoint-sites/
